# InDesign retaining copies of unlinked and unembedded files inside .indd file

Tags: adobe-indesign, embed

Had InDesign document that was very small, much less than 1GB. I added some .psd files to my InDesign document and embedded them. The InDesign document was now 3.7GB. I then reduced the size of the source .psd files to ~10% of their original size and updated the links (same filenames, updated files) in InDesign and embedded these. The file size increased by 10% instead of decreasing by 90%. I think the old copies of the .psd files are still in there (in addition to the updated files). I have tried unembedding everything and saving. File size remains unchanged. Those old files appear to be stuck in there. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

I found a thread on Reddit where someone had the same problem. The solution: Save As. Worked for me.

Comment: save as indeed fixes this